# How to implement a recursive relationship with SQLite-Net Extentions

Tags: c#, recursion, relationship, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have a table **Employee** that must have a *recursive relationship* eg.

**Row 1:** *EmployeeId* = **1**, *EmployeeName* = **Albert**, *SupervisorId* = **NULL**;

**Row 2**: *EmployeeId* = **2**, *EmployeeName* = **Leonardo**, *SupervisorId* = **1**;

i.e. EmployeeId(**2**) is a child of EmployeeId(**1**)

I have the following code in C# in which I use [SQLite-Net Extentions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/overview) to implement a recursive relationship:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Subordinates = new List<Employee>();
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string EmployeeGuid { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [OneToMany("SupervisorGuid")]
    public List<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne("EmployeeGuid")]
    public Employee Supervisor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Employee))]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string SupervisorGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Next I test the code- I create *two* Employees and add them to the table *Employee*:

*1st* Employee

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee
{
    EmployeeGuid = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
    EmployeeName = "Albert"
};

Insert(employee1);
```

*2nd* Employee

```
Employee employee2 = new Employee
{
    EmployeeGuid = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb",
    EmployeeName = "Leonardo",
    SupervisorGuid = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
};

Insert(employee2);
```

BUT when I do a call

```
GetByGuid(string guid)
```

with *guid* being of the 1st employee, I get the following error:

> Additional information: Object of type 'Project.Models.Employee' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Does SQLite-Net support recursive relationships? Any suggestions please?

**UPDATE**

Code for GetByGuid():

```
public T GetByGuid(string guid)
{
    return Database.GetWithChildren<T>(guid);
}
```

Also when I add the *2nd* Employee without specifying the Foreign Key and do the call it works...

Comment: Can you show the code of `GetByGuid` or is this a built-in method of the SQLite-extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recursive relationships you have to manually specify inverse relationships, like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string EmployeeGuid { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(inverseProperty: "Supervisor")]
    public List<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(inverseProperty: "Subordinates")]
    public Employee Supervisor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Employee))]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string SupervisorGuid { get; set; }
}
```

I've tested it and this works as expected. However, I've created [a new issue in bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issue/17/improve-discovery-of-inverse-relationship) because I think that this behavior can be improved so this case will work in a near future:

```
public class Employee
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string EmployeeGuid { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Employee Supervisor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Employee))]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string SupervisorGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `GetWithChildren` does not return `T`, but `List<T>`, so you need to do e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByGuid(string guid)
{
    return Database.GetWithChildren<T>(guid);
}
```

or if you only want the item with the supplied `Guid`:

```
public T GetByGuid(string guid)
{
    return Database.GetWithChildren<T>(guid)
               .FirstOrDefault(i => i.EmployeeGuid == guid);
}
```

But then `GetWithChildren` is possibly the wrong method.

Comment: GetWithChildren() can only return one element but it is returning a collection as you have stated- so I'll try and find a work-around

Comment: If thats the case you can use `Database.GetWithChildren<T>(guid).FirstOrDefault()`.